# JvMail (JEDI) component not sending mail

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, jedi

JvMail component is not functioning right or I am messing 
something up.

```
procedure TForm1.RzURLLabel1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if cxLookUpComboBox1.Text ='' then
abort else
with JvMail1.SimpleMAPI do
begin
JvMail1.Clear;
JvMail1.Recipient.AddRecipient('smtp:mymail@gmail.com');
JvMail1.Subject := 'Password lost  ';
JvMail1.Body.Text := 'Request password  :' +#13#10+  cxLookUpComboBox1.Text +#13#10+  AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[4].Text ;
JvMail1.SendMail;
end
end;
```

My mail does not get sent unless I put the prefix 'smtp:' infront of the mail adress.
Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvMailRecipients.AddRecipient) is clear to that

> **Notes:**
>
> The format of an address specified by parameter Address is **[address
>   type][e-mail address]**. Examples of valid addresses are
>   FAX:206-555-1212 and SMTP:M@X.COM.
>
> **Description:**
>
> The following code adds a recipient to the Recipient list:
>   `JvMail1.Recipient.AddRecipient('SMTP:someone@somedomain.com', 'Some one');`

Comment: Actually, I have seen plenty of examples on the web but none with smtp prefix.Actually it was from Mike Shkolnik I learned of this prefix and he only indicated it for use in case of trouble. Thats why I tought it was a nuisance.... Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I don't provide any other solution or awesome in depth explanation on why you need to add smtp, so feel free to downvote this answer. :)

You already have a workaround, so instead I'll give some real world advice on how to fix this:

1. Just prepend the damn `smtp:` via code if that's what it takes
2. Write a TODO comment that says you need to figure out what's going on here
3. Move on to your next task

Of course, unless sending email is really at the core of your application, or if you really have nothing better to do.

Comment: Problem with SMTP is that it stays visible in Outlook which is kind of ugly. Not that it bothers me much ...